# Is graph coloring complete for poly-APX?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, approximation-hardness, graph-colouring, open-problem, apx

Is the graph coloring problem complete for poly-APX under C-reductions
(alternatively, under AP-reductions)? For the graph coloring problem, speaking of a feasible solution means a proper coloring for all vertices of the given graph.

The complexity class poly-APX contains all NP optimization problems that can be
approximated within a factor that is polynomial in the size of the
input. The notion of C-reducibility concerns approximation preserving
reductions, which keep the performance ratio of the feasible solutions
under consideration within a linear factor. For definitions regarding
approximation preserving reducibilities, see [P. Crescenzi: A short guide to approximation preserving reducibilites, CCC '97](http://lcbb4.epfl.ch/reading/np/guideApproxPreservingReduc.pdf).

**EDIT (1.8.2014):**
Somewhat related, I've found in the paper "on syntactic versus computational views of approximability" by Khanna, Motwani, Sudan and Vazirani (SICOMP 28(1):164-191) a remark stating that GRAPH COLORING and MAX CLIQUE are both in poly-APX-PB and interreducible (Remark 6 in that paper). I understand this is meant with respect to E-reducibility defined in that paper. Later, in the sketch of proof of Theorem 6 in that paper, I understand that they imply that MAX CLIQUE is complete for poly-APX-PB under E-reductions. I would also be grateful for a proof that GRAPH COLORING is complete for poly-APX-PB w.r.t. E-reducibility.

Comment: Somewhat up-to-date optimization results are usually at http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/problemlist/ ; Minimum Graph Coloring is at http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node15.html

Comment: argentpepper, Thanks for the hint. But I've checked the compendium before asking the question. Unfortunately it does not give any clues about poly-APX-completeness of graph coloring. By the way, is the webpage with the compendium still maintained?

Comment: I don't know...